# grey_accessibilityLabel("Login") doesn't match element that exists in UI hierarchy with the same accessibility label

Tags: xctest, earlgrey

I am using this code to click on the login button:

```
[[EarlGrey selectElementWithMatcher:grey_accessibilityLabel("Login")] performAction:grey_tap()];
```

However, it fails with the following error:

> No elements found

The relevant element in the UI hierarchy dumped on failure looks like:

```
<UIButton:0x7fcb01d963d0; AX=N; AX.label='Login'; AX.frame={{16, 64}, {124, 64}}; AX.activationPoint={78, 96}; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitLink'; AX.focused='N'>
```

What's the right way of clicking on the login button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added [AX=N matching to the EarlGrey FAQ.](https://github.com/google/EarlGrey/pull/130)

> **How do I match elements that are denoted with "AX=N" in the view hierarchy?**
>
> EarlGrey's view hierarchy identifies non-accessible elements with
>   `AX=N`. Accessibility IDs can be added to both accessible and
>   non-accessible elements. When searching for AX=N elements, the
>   following accessibility matchers won't work:
>
> - `grey_accessibilityLabel`
> - `grey_accessibilityValue`
> - `grey_accessibilityTrait`
> - `grey_accessibilityHint`
>
> If the `AX=N` element can't be matched by `grey_accessibilityID`, then
>   you'll have to use non-accessibility matchers to locate the element.

I'd fix the button so that it's accessible, then the label matcher will work.